# Postgres different default value per child table?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have two subtables with data loaded via COPY. Is there a way to provide a default value for a column defined as common in the parent table? Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    name            text,
    source          text
);

CREATE TABLE person_a (
    LIKE person INCLUDING ALL,
    source text default 'dmv'
) INHERITS (person);

CREATE TABLE person_b (
    LIKE person INCLUDING ALL,
    source text default 'irs'
) INHERITS (person);
```

That, however, doesn't work. I tells me "source" is already defined. If I remove the LIKE expression, it works, but then I don't get equivalent copies of all the indexes and I need those.

My use case is that I'm importing (via COPY) data from multiple files. They are the exact same format, just different sources. And I want to keep them in different tables because sometimes I reference specific source and for performance reasons. There's no way with COPY to indicate the source, so I'm doing it with different tables. I still need to distinguish which table each record comes from though if I'm querying against the parent table.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres 12, to have different default values for an inherited column even with LIKE?

I'm guessing no, but maybe there's some clever way to do it through some followup after the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution to [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63905091/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

I like a question that is already an answer:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    name            text,
    source          text
);

CREATE TABLE person_a (
    source text default 'dmv'
) INHERITS (person);

CREATE TABLE person_b (
    source text default 'irs'
) INHERITS (person);

test(5432)=> \d person
             Table "public.person"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 name   | text |           |          | 
 source | text |           |          | 
Number of child tables: 2 (Use \d+ to list them.)

test(5432)=> \d person_a
              Table "public.person_a"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable |   Default   
--------+------+-----------+----------+-------------
 name   | text |           |          | 
 source | text |           |          | 'dmv'::text
Inherits: person

test(5432)=> \d person_b
              Table "public.person_b"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable |   Default   
--------+------+-----------+----------+-------------
 name   | text |           |          | 
 source | text |           |          | 'irs'::text
Inherits: person
```

Comment: Oh, bizarre, I must have screwed up something because I couldn't get it to work. Thanks for the detailed outputs!

Comment: Ah, I'm using LIKE to bring along all indexes:  LIKE person INCLUDING ALL. It complains: column "source" specified more than once.

Comment: Well `LIKE` and `INHERITS` can not exist in same query so can you amend your question to detail the entirety of what you want?

Comment: The error message says they can't. `LIKE` and `INHERITS` are orthogonal to each other. The former create a new table that is detached form the original and the latter creates a table that is still tied to the original table. You can't have both. Just because you string commands together does not guarantee they make sense.